# JRebel remote server as a Service

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, oracle11g, jrebel

JRebel has the possibility to deploy an application on a remote server.
To do this, according to the documentation, the JRebel agent should be put in the server boot.

Later tools like Eclipse provide the [ability to connect to the remote server](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/quickstart/eclipse/) and deploy the application.

According to the documentation in the Eclipse plugin the URL of the remote server is simply indicated.

Doubts:

1. **[Server level]** Is possible to develop into a JRebel-enabled server, its own service, as a kind of customized end point receiver for deploy jrebel requests ... ? The idea would be to have a unique "JRebel_Deploy_Receiver_As_A_Service" url
2. **[CLIENT level]** Is possible to develop a custom client application, instead of being Eclipse o other marketplace tool.. In other words, to develop a client for deploy against a JRebel enabled server in the given endpoint?

Answer (score -1):

There are no current plans for developing standalone utility to sync changes to remote JRebel server via the remote protocol used in IDEs. As for server-side, it's difficult to understand what would be the purpose. If all you want is to push files to server, there are plentiful of applications allowing you to do this, e.g. [RSync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync).

Comment: @RSync just push files to server, but not deploys an aplication into a Container Server..... The purpose wold be enable JRebel as a service, just to use your own client application and a enabled endpoint to receipt requests to deploy into a enabled server

Comment: On server side the remote request receiver is tightly tied to the application server implementation and the instance of it, so it couldn't be a standalone service.